# I get this error when i want to run my django app :

Tags: python, django

ImportError: cannot import name 'froms' from 'django'

Comment: Probably you have a typo somewhere in your code, it should be forms not froms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your "froms" spelling is incorrect. I think that you are trying to work with forms in django. The correct spelling is "forms"

Comment: Whilst correct, a single users typo is unlikely to be helpful to future readers so this question would be better closed/deleted